# Использование функции filter, list, .join

Tags: python, python-3.x

Реализовать функцию, которая получает на вход некоторый перечень паролей. Функция должна вернуть только правильные пароли через запятую ( , ). Правильность пароля определяется согласно **следующим критериям**:

*длина пароля не менее 6 символов ;*

*пароль обязательно должен включать цифры ;*

*пароль обязательно должен включать строчные буквы ;*

*пароль обязательно должен включать заглавные буквы.*

Если в перечне паролей нет правильных, в качестве результата функция должна вернуть строку  'empty result'.

**Требования к реализации:**

*Использование функции filter*

*Для хранения перечня паролей использовать список list*

*Для формирования результата использовать .join()*

*Входные и выходные данные - строки str*

Мой код

```
def solve(passwords):
    def check(num):
        if len(num)>=6 and(not num.isalpha()) and (not num.isdigit()) and (not num.islower()):
            return num
  
    passwords=list(filter(check, passwords))
    if passwords==[]:
        passwords='empty result'
    else:
        passwords=','.join(passwords)      
    return passwords
```

Не проходит все тесты, подскажите в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: а входные данные какие, тоже пароли через запятую? как вы их выделяете?

Comment: input().split(';')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нашел пароль, который ломает ваш алгоритм: `'      '` (6 пробелов) - он считается корректным, хотя не должен :)

поэтому или учтите, что она может не содержать ни букв ни цифр и быть некорректной или измените свое условие:

```
and(not num.isalpha()) and (not num.isdigit()) and (not num.islower())
```

честно говоря данное условие так себе в плане корректности

P.S.

вот такая функция подошла бы:

```
def check(num):
    return len(num) >= 6 and any(map(lambda l: l.isdigit(), num)) and any(map(lambda l: l.isupper(), num)) and any(map(lambda l: l.islower(), num))
```

Comment: место `lambda l: l.isdigit()` мне кажется лучше написать `str.isdigit`